# To show the ice:collapsiblePanel as expanded

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I have a collapsible panel in jsf . I want the panel to be by default in expanded mode .But currently whenever I navigate to the menu it shows as collapsed . Thing is when I refresh the page by f5 ,it loads as expanded . 
I have set the **expanded="true"** property .

**My xhtml -**

```
<ice:panelCollapsible id="sPnlClpsblMyCampnResults2" expanded="true" border="0"
                                         actionListener="#{baseBean.collapsiblePanelactionListener}">
```

**Bean class**

```
public void collapsiblePanelactionListener(final ActionEvent actionEvent) {
              if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                     logger.info(LOG_METHOD_ENTER);
              }
              if (actionEvent.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.ANY_PHASE) {
                     actionEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
                     actionEvent.queue();
              }

              getBaseBean().getErrorMessagesList().clear();
              final PanelCollapsible panelCollapsible = (PanelCollapsible) actionEvent
                           .getComponent();
              if (panelCollapsible.getChildCount() > 0) {

                     if (panelCollapsible.getChildren().get(0) instanceof HtmlPanelGroup) {

                           final HtmlPanelGroup panelGrp = (HtmlPanelGroup) panelCollapsible
                                         .getChildren().get(0);
                           if (panelCollapsible.isExpanded()) {
                                  panelGrp.setEffect(new SlideDown());
                           } else {
                                  panelGrp.setEffect(new SlideUp());
                           }
                           panelGrp.getEffect().setTransitory(false);
                           panelGrp.getEffect().setSubmit(true);
                     }
              }
       }
```

How can I achieve the expanded property ?